# Facebook .net toolkit v3 getAlbums gives error

Tags: .net, facebook, toolkit

Having a problem when using the getAlbums method... I have passed in the correct long uid to the method but it gave me an error: Input string incorrect exception stuff. I sure that I passed in the correct facebook user id.

Does anyone has the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is a logged bug for this.
Check this link:
http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=72848

I'm having the same problem ... Rebuilding the sources and setting nullable values may be a workaround, apparently.